# PHP Mail Function - Add external image

Tags: php, gmail, mime

I'm trying to add an image stored on my server to the email sent with PHP's mail() function. Here's the php code below:

```
$subject = 'Password Reset';

$message = '
<html>
<head>
    <title>Password Reset</title>
</head>
<body>
    Salve '.$username.', utilizza questo link per resettare la password: <a href="https://gestionale.boscarato.eu/Elaborato/reset/reset_password.php?c='.$operation_code.'">Resetta la tua password </a>
    <br><br>
    <img src="http://gestionale.boscarato.eu/Elaborato/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="300" height="50">
    <br>
    Cordiali saluti,
    <br>
    <h5>Luca Boscarato [5E] </h5>
</body>
</html>
';

$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: Luca Boscarato <boscarato.luca@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The problem is that the image can't be shown (I've already activated the 'accept-all' option on gmail so that my client accepts external images too.

Comment: why don't you try phpmailer with html true ?? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: is it typomistake or not dont know.. but u missed = for alt in image source... alt="Logo"

Comment: I added the '=' but I can't see the image anyway

Comment: ok... can you try with another image link ??

Comment: Can you check in browser? Because I have checked it and it respond me this sites can't  be reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `http://` protocol (in the image URL) to `https://`.

The error is caused by incorrect configuration of the remote server.

HTTPS loads correctly

```
https://gestionale.boscarato.eu/Elaborato/images/logo.png  # HTTPS correct
```

---

But HTTP redirects to invalid URL

```
http://gestionale.boscarato.eu/Elaborato/images/logo.png  # HTTP before redirect
```

redirects to

```
https://gestionale.boscarato.euelaborato/images/logo.png  # invalid URL
```

Mind the missing slash after the `.eu` TLD.

```
curl -I "http://gestionale.boscarato.eu/Elaborato/images/logo.png"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 14 May 2021 19:21:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Raspbian)
Location: https://gestionale.boscarato.euElaborato/images/logo.png
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: That's actually not the first time the / gets removed. In the configuration file of apache I set the redirect from HTTP to HTTPs but it seems to lose the / between eu and Elaborato sometimes, do you have any idea of what could be the cause? This happens to me when I directly write it into the browser too.

Comment: By the way it's not working even though I replaced http with https

Comment: Could it be because of my invalid https ceritficate (talking about the apache server)? Since I'm implementing this system just for some tests.

Comment: @Shark44 It's caused by incorrect configuration of the HTTP server (apache, nginx, ...). If you have access to the server configuration, you need to fix the redirect rules. They might possibly in `.htaccess` (Apache) of your site, `/etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled/yoursite.conf`, your sites vhost config, can be pretty much in any config that you've updated.

Comment: I can see now that the HTTPS `curl` request returns an "self-signed certificate" warning that I didn't pay much attention to when testing the image in browser. The self-signed cert is the reason why Gmail refuses to display the image on HTTPS. You should fix this too by using SSL certificate that is verified by a certification authority (e.g. Let's encrypt), not self-signed.

Comment: Oh ok so basically it would work with a valid certificate, that's fine to me, I just wanted to test it, thank you.